# Xamarin.Android Detect Emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

For iPhone I can detect that the app is running in a Simulator by doing this:

```
var isSumlator = ObjCRuntime.Runtime.Arch == ObjCRuntime.Arch.SIMULATOR;
```

What is the best equivalent for detecting the emulator in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends upon your goal of if this is just for local debug testing or if you plan to leave it in your code for testing within an end-user environment.

As the world of Android is quite large, this is an ever evolving method based upon what we *seen in the wild*:

```
public bool isEmulator(bool LicensedPlayers = false)
{
    var detect = 0;
    try
    {
        var teleManager = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
        string networkOperator = "";
        try
        {
            networkOperator = teleManager.NetworkOperator;
            if (LicensedPlayers)
            {
                if ((teleManager.NetworkOperatorName == "T-Mobile") && 
                    (Build.Radio == "unknown") && 
                    (Build.Serial == "unknown") && 
                    (Build.Manufacturer == "samsung"))
                {
                    D.WriteLine("BlueStacks (OS-X) Player");
                    detect += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            networkOperator = "";
            D.WriteLine("TelephonyService Exceptiion, custom emulator");
            detect += 1;
        }
        if (networkOperator.Contains("Android"))
        {
            D.WriteLine("Google's Android Emulator");
            detect += 1;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        D.WriteLine("TelephonyService not available, custom emulator");
        detect += 1;
    }
    if (LicensedPlayers)
    {
        if (Build.Display.Contains("andy") || (Build.Hardware.Contains("andy")))
        {
            D.WriteLine("Andy Player");
            detect += 1;
        }
    }
    if (Build.Hardware.Contains("goldfish"))
    {
        D.WriteLine("Goldfish-based Emulator");
        detect += 1;
    }
    if (Build.Display.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("xamarin"))
    {
        D.WriteLine("Xamarin Android Player");
        detect += 1;
    }
    if (Build.Hardware.Contains("vsemu"))
    {
        D.WriteLine("Visual Studio Android Emulator");
        detect += 1;
    }
    if (Build.Host.Contains("genymobile") || (Build.Manufacturer.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("genymotion")))
    {
        D.WriteLine("Genymotion Android Emulator");
        detect += 1;
    }
    if (Build.Hardware.Contains("vbox") && Build.Hardware.Contains("86"))
    {
        D.WriteLine("VirtualBox-based Emulator");
        detect += 1;
    }
    return detect > 0;
}
```

---

Updated: Fixed XAP emulator detection on multiple platforms

Answer (score 20):

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

var isSimulator = DeviceInfo.DeviceType == DeviceType.Virtual;
```

Comment: Good, that's why I like Xamarin, these built in function save a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

[Source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34275/detect-if-simulator-or-device)

```
string fing = Build.Fingerprint;
bool isEmulator=false;

if (fing != null) {
  isEmulator =  fing.Contains("vbox") || fing.Contains("generic") || fing.Contains("vsemu");
}
```

Comment: FYI: Lots of phones (Chinese-based and CyanogenMod-based builds) contain `generic` in their fingerprint.