# Mobile or Simulator at runtime

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to enable a logger service only when I'm running on a real android\iOS device. 
Is it possible to know if I'm running with a android\iOS simulator or a real device at run time in core project level?

Answer (score 2):

Create an **Interface** in the Core project:

```
public interface IDevicePlatform 
{ 
    bool IsSimulator(); 
}
```

**iOS DependencyService** Registration/Implementation:

```
public class Platform_iOS : IDevicePlatform 
{  
    public IsSimulator() 
    { 
        return ObjCRuntime.Runtime.Arch == ObjCRuntime.Arch.SIMULATOR;
    }
}
```

**Android DependencyService** Registration/Implementation:

```
public class Platform_Android : IDevicePlatform 
{ 
    public bool IsSimulator() 
    { 
        if (Build.Fingerprint != null) 
        { 
            if (Build.Fingerprint.Contains("vbox") ||  Build.Fingerprint.Contains("generic") || Build.Fingerprint.Contains("vsemu"))
                return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Call it in Core as:

```
bool isSimulator = DependencyService.Get<IDevicePlatform>().IsSimulator();
if(isSimulator)
{
    //You are running on the Simulator
}
else
{
    //You are running on the real device
}
```

**NOTE**: iOS implementation is straight forward while, Android is a wide world, so, apart from above simple android implementation, also have a look at [SushiHangover's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283184/xamarin-android-detect-emulator)